# Javascript CSS3 Listener Not Being Caught For webkit*End

Tags: javascript, css

I am trying to catch CSS effects ending in javascript. But for some reason, the eventListener is not catching any. Specifically, when css effect from class phoneQueue class is done, I would like javascript to catch the event when it is done. I have tried webkitTransformEnd, webkitTransitionEnd, and webkitAnimationEnd and can not get the event to fireoff. How come the event(no matter which I try) isn't being caught?

```
function rotateLists() {
    var eventType =  "webkitTransformEnd";
    document.addEventListener("eventType", function () { alert("hi"); }, false);
    var phone = document.getElementById("phoneQueue");
    var chat = document.getElementById("chatQueue");
    phone.classList.add("phoneQueueOff");
    setTimeout(function () {  
        chat.classList.toggle("visible"); 

        chat.classList.add("chatQueueOn") }, 2000);

}
```

CSS3:

```
.phoneQueueOff, .chatQueueOff {
    -webkit-transform: rotateY(60deg);
    -webkit-transition-duration: 2s;
}

.phoneQueueOn, .chatQueueOn {
    -webkit-animation: spinY 2s;
}

@-webkit-keyframes spinY
{
    0%   {-webkit-transform: rotateY(90deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0% 5;}
    100% {-webkit-transform: rotateY(0deg); -webkit-transform-origin: 0% 0% 5;}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener("eventType", function () { alert("hi"); }, false);
```

should be

```
document.addEventListener(eventType, function () { alert("hi"); }, false);
```

because `eventType` is a variable, not the name of an event.

Comment: Also, I believe the event name is `WebKitTransformEnd`, with way too many uppercase letters.

Comment: @NiettheDarkAbsol: I had written a comment about that; we’ll see. Can’t test it